# Subsurface problem in 4.0

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, color, subsurface-scattering

I'm trying to render a character using the Random Walk (skin) mode in the Subsurface section. When the character is in a standard white base color, there's surface scattering but when I turn the base color blue, there's no subsurface scattering. What do I do?

[image]

Comment: Hello, what does it give if you increase the Scale value under Subsurface in the Principled BSDF?

Comment: Increase by how much? The scale is currently at 3.

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=OG2q5Dg5" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/OG2q5Dg5/)

Comment: it seems to work fine, make sure that the RGB values are correct (if you want a blue subsurface color, increase the third value), also make sure that the copy of the body is disabled for render in the Outliner: https://www.zupimages.net/up/24/05/mh04.jpg

Comment: I want a red subsurface for a blue character.

Comment: maybe check this answer? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xV_dQGOGcY